# Wildfly Security Manager not processing JndiPermission

Tags: wildfly, jndi, securitymanager

I'm trying to get my existing application to work with the Wildfly Security Manager.  To start, I'm running my applications and adding the configuration that I need to standalone.xml like this in response to exceptions in the application log file:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security-manager:1.0">
    <deployment-permissions>
        <minimum-set>
            <permission class="java.util.PropertyPermission" name="*" actions="read,write"/>
            <permission .../>
        </minimum-set>
    </deployment-permissions>
</subsystem>
```

This is working okay, until I get to the following exception:

```
2017-01-03 16:00:22,119 ERROR [com.myapp.ClusteredCache] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) Failed to bind to JNDI name: java.security.AccessControlException: WFSM000001: Permission check failed (permission "("org.wildfly.naming.java.permission.JndiPermission" "/AppCacheImpl" "bind")" in code source "(vfs:/content/myapp-wildfly.jar <no signer certificates>)" of "null")
        at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.checkPermission(WildFlySecurityManager.java:273) [wildfly-elytron-1.0.2.Final.jar:1.0.2.Final]
        ...
```

I add a permission like this:

```
<permission class="org.wildfly.naming.java.permission.JndiPermission" name="-" actions="all"/>
```

or:

```
<permission class="org.wildfly.naming.java.permission.JndiPermission" name="&lt;&lt;ALL BINDINGS&gt;&gt;" actions="all"/>
```

or even specifically:

```
<permission class="org.wildfly.naming.java.permission.JndiPermission" name="/AppCacheImpl" actions="bind"/>
```

but WildFly still throws the exception. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Update: I've been debugging into the WildFly 10.1 and wildfly-elytron code.  I notice that the issue is that WildFly throws a ClassNotFoundException on the JndiPermission class.

The class exists in the wildfly-naming module (org.jboss.as.naming) but has a different module path as everything else in that jar (org.wildfly.naming.java.permission.JndiPermission) so maybe there is something special to do here?

Answer (score 0):

This was a class loading error.  Because of how JndiPermission is specified in the wildfly-naming module, you need to specify a module attribute, like this:

```
<permission 
    module="org.jboss.as.naming" 
    class="org.wildfly.naming.java.permission.JndiPermission" 
    name="-" 
    actions="all"/>
```